# Increase from previous value by condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I was searching for an answer to my specific problem, but I didn't find a conclusion.

I have a dataframe with data

```
ID  a
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   0
8   1
9   1
10  0
11  1
12  0
13  0
```

Now i want to add "b" column with number increase from previous b if a == 1

Result like this

```
ID  a   b
1   0   0
2   0   0
3   1   1
4   1   2
5   1   3
6   1   4
7   0   0
8   1   1
9   1   2
10  0   0
11  1   1
12  0   0
13  0   0
14  1   1
15  1   2
16  1   3
17  1   4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` an option can be to group on `cumsum(a==0)`. This will create a group which got a previous row (if available with `a=0` for all rows with `a=1`. Now, `lag(cumsum(a==1))` will provide expected count.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(a==0)) %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(a==1, lag(cumsum(a==1))+1,0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#    ID a b
# 1   1 0 0
# 2   2 0 0
# 3   3 1 1
# 4   4 1 2
# 5   5 1 3
# 6   6 1 4
# 7   7 0 0
# 8   8 1 1
# 9   9 1 2
# 10 10 0 0
# 11 11 1 1
# 12 12 0 0
# 13 13 0 0
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
ID  a
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   0
8   1
9   1
10  0
11  1
12  0
13  0",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach that uses `rleid()` from `data.table` to create a grouping variable that we use inside `ave()`. We then calculate the `cumsum` per group which will be `0` whenever `a == 0`.

```
library(data.table)
df$new_b <- with(df, ave(a, rleid(a), FUN = cumsum))
df
#   ID a b new_b
#1   1 0 0     0
#2   2 0 0     0
#3   3 1 1     1
#4   4 1 2     2
#5   5 1 3     3
#6   6 1 4     4
#7   7 0 0     0
#8   8 1 1     1
#9   9 1 2     2
#10 10 0 0     0
#11 11 1 1     1
#12 12 0 0     0
#13 13 0 0     0
#14 14 1 1     1
#15 15 1 2     2
#16 16 1 3     3
#17 17 1 4     4
```

---

Once `data.table` is loaded you could also do

```
setDT(df)[, new_b := cumsum(a), rleid(a)][]
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:17, a = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), b = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)), .Names = c("ID", 
"a", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following using base R's `rle`

```
df$b <- unlist(mapply(
    function(len, val) if (val == 0) rep(0, len) else 1:len,
    rle(df$a)$lengths, rle(df$a)$values));
df;
#   ID a b
#1   1 0 0
#2   2 0 0
#3   3 1 1
#4   4 1 2
#5   5 1 3
#6   6 1 4
#7   7 0 0
#8   8 1 1
#9   9 1 2
#10 10 0 0
#11 11 1 1
#12 12 0 0
#13 13 0 0
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "ID  a
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   0
8   1
9   1
10  0
11  1
12  0
13  0", header = T)
```

Comment: Yeah!! Thank you very much for help

Comment: Our result matches which means solutions are correct. I was slightly confused by `OP's` expected data having 17 rows.

Comment: @MKR Yes so was I; I think OP must've used a slightly different input data for his expected output. @markus posted a a nice (and earlier) answer using `data.table::rleid`, that he took down again, perhaps also because of this confusion. A pity.

Comment: You're very welcome @Quý!

Comment: @MauritsEvers Undeleted my answer after reading your comment.